# Antd Table Skip page: No Data

Tags: reactjs, pagination, apollo, react-apollo, antd

I call an [offset-based paginated GraphQL endpoint](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/pagination.html#numbered-pages). The data then gets displayed in an [Antd Table](https://ant.design/components/table/).

Now, when clicking trough the pages, everything works as expected: Data gets fetched and appended to the previously fetched data.
If a page is skipped however, the same routine is triggered.

E.g.

```
const previousData = [10, 11, 12]; // we are on page 1
// fetchMore && updateQuery, going to page 3 directly
const updatedData = [10, 11, 12, 30, 31, 32];

// Antd Table tries to access data on page 3, therefore at index behind item 32,
// as the page 3 items are in the place of page 2 items
```

This is somewhat expected behaviour, I am only interested in the data on page one and three so far, not page two. However, Antd Table tries to show the data on page three by skipping the first two pages while assuming a page size of 3 items per page.
Therefore, `pageSize * currentOffset = 3 * 1 = 6` it tries to access out of range data and says "No Data".

Is there a way to bypass that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh. My. God.
I have found the answer myself.

The issue was that I merged the data myself like such:

```
const mergedData = [...previousData, ...updatedData]
```

and then used this for display.

Apparently, this is not the way to go.
Rather **replace your existing data** completely.

So now what I am doing in the Apollo `fetchMore` is this:

```
updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => fetchMoreResult,
```

Now, everything works as intended.